# Aggregate daily data with means

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset as sampled below, and I want to convert daily data to monthly while having the averages of total_cases_per_million and stringency_index.

```
head(datacovid)
 location                 date                         total_cases_per_million    stringency_index
 Afghanistan              24/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 Colombia                 25/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 Democratic Republic of Congo 26/02/2020               0.026                      8.33
 India                    27/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 Iraq                     28/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 Lebanon                  29/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
```

The structure is as follows:

> str(datacovid)
> 'data.frame':   78444 obs. of  4 variables:
> $ location               : chr  "Afghanistan" "Colombia" "Democratic Republic of Congo" "India" ...
> $ date                   : Factor w/ 455 levels "01/01/2020","01/01/2021",..: 348 363 378 393 408 423 5 20 35 50 ...
> $ total_cases_per_million: num  0.026 0.026 0.026 0.026 0.026 0.026 0.026 0.026 0.051 0.103 ...
> $ stringency_index       : num  8.33 8.33 8.33 8.33 8.33 ...

I have attemped to use "mutate" but failed. Many thanks in advance.
P.S. I am a very R beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is to group the data by `month`. Converting the date variable into date type would help.

```r
df = read.table(text = r'{location                 date                         total_cases_per_million    stringency_index
 Afghanistan              24/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 Colombia                 25/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 'Democratic Republic of Congo' 26/02/2020               0.026                      8.33
 India                    27/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 Iraq                     28/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33
 Lebanon                  29/02/2020                   0.026                      8.33}', header=T)

df$date = as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
df$month  = format(df$date, "%b")
aggregate(cbind(total_cases_per_million, stringency_index) ~ month, df, mean)

# month total_cases_per_million stringency_index
# 1   Feb                   0.026             8.33
```

Comment: Glad that helped.

Comment: As I work on this, after the functions you highlight ı cant see the country names @Eyayaw B.

Comment: adjust the code by adding` location` on the rhs of the formula:  `~ month + location`.

Comment: appreciate @Eyayaw, now it is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using `lubridate` to transform the date column into date format and `tidyverse` to group and summarise. Here's the commented code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  # Transform date column into date format
  mutate_at(vars(date), function(x) dmy(as.character(x))) %>%
  # Extract month from date
  mutate(var_month = month(date)) %>%
  # Group by month
  group_by(var_month) %>%
  # Calculate the average for cases and stringency, grouped by month
  summarise(avg_monthly_cases = mean(total_cases_per_million),
            avg_stringency = mean(stringency_index))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  var_month avg_monthly_cases avg_stringency
#      <dbl>             <dbl>          <dbl>
#1         2             0.026           8.33
```

Comment: Many thanks @Jonathan. I have the warning message below; Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` input `date`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
i Input `date` is `(function (..., quiet = FALSE, tz = NULL, locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"), ...`.

Comment: Probably that's caused by the fact that date is coded as a factor (just re-read your post). I just edited the answer to transform the date column to character, prior to transforming it to date format.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan for your time. It is likely because of me but I couldnt manage to fix this.